# Get notification on any updates performed on PHP LDAP Server

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I have integrated PHP LDAP server on my server by following this [guide](https://www.unixmen.com/install-openldap-in-ubuntu-15-10-and-debian-8/). (Complete LDAP reference is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php).)

I have displayed the users list which are available on LDAP server. Our application gets connected to many LDAP servers like one-many relationship, each user has LDAP server.

**Now, I want my application to get a notification whenever there is a insert/update/delete (CRUD) operation performed on each user's LDAP server. I need Notifications for how many new records have been inserted/updated/deleted to LDAP server**.

I have googled it but did not find any solution. I have a doubt, is this really possible to get notifications about any updates happened to LDAP server? If yes, can anyone please explain how to achieve this?

My code to LDAP connection & display users:

```
$domain = 'unixmen.local';
$username = 'cn=admin,dc=unixmen,dc=local';
$password = '****';
define('HOSTNAME','ldap://127.0.0.1');
$ldap_conn = ldap_connect(HOSTNAME,389) or die("Could not connect to ldap server");
ldap_set_option($ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
$dn="ou=sales,dc=unixmen,dc=local";
$filter='(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid=*))';
$result=ldap_search($ldap_conn, $dn, $filter, array("cn", "dn", "givenName", "uidNumber", "sn"));
for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++)
{
  $users[$i]["full_name"] = $info[$i]["cn"][0];
  $users[$i]["first_name"] = $info[$i]["givenname"][0];
  $users[$i]["last_name"] = $info[$i]["sn"][0];
  $users[$i]["uid_number"] = $info[$i]["uidnumber"][0];
}
print_r($users);
```

Comment: I still did not find any solution, Any one please help me to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is an LDAP extension, that allows a server to notify a client application when entries are created, updated or deleted: LDAP Persistent Search control (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-ldapext-psearch-03).
As the extension is not an approved standard, not all servers support it, and thus I don't think there is support for it in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Is there any other library (or) API for LDAP extension to notify a client application? that too it has to be written in PHP..! Any solution please

Comment: I'm not aware of other PHP LDAP libraries, but PHP is definitely not my main language of interest.

Comment: Can you please tell how to use that Library/SDK ( https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-ldapext-psearch-03 ). I have read that but I did not find any guide on 'how to use/install on server' (or) download option there...! Please assist me on this.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your comment. The link is to an internet-draft which specifies the protocol. It's not an implementation. You need to find a library or an SDK that implements it, or you need to extend your PHP library to implement it. As for the server side, many LDAP servers implement this extension and it doesn't require specific configuration afaik.